# Postgresql: Unable to connect through psql at console to default localhost

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql server running and verified on 5432 on my localhost system:

If I type: `psql -l` I get the following response:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

If I type `psql -h localhost -l`, it works and gives me a list of the databases.

The `pg_hba.conf` file is wide open, showing:

```
TYPE    DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
```

The value "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

Allow any IP to connect without password:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

IPv4 local connections:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

IPv6 local connections:

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

What have I missed? On other systems the first call from the command line works fine.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like when you are running the command you are connecting to localhost, not the file socket.. try

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432
```

Answer (score 4):

Default Admin Login  `sudo -u postgres psql`

Login into specific db with privilages `psql -h host -p port -U User_Name db_name`

Answer (score 1):

> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

This just means that the `unix_socket_directory` configuration parameter on the server differs from the default of the client-side psql.

`/var/run/postgresql` is the default Unix domain socket path for Debian-based packages. For a self-compiled server, it is `/tmp`. It may also be a custom path specified in `postgresql.conf` or through a start directive.

Assuming it's `/tmp` you could do `psql -l -h /tmp`. The command knows that the parameter following `-h` is to be interpreted as a directory and not as a hostname because it starts with a slash.

Comment: If this command works `psql -U postgres -h /tmp`, or this one `su - postgres -c "psql -h /tmp"` , then you should find a solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50055155/3412316

Comment: @Kiruahxh: but note that the solution is a band aid that won't resist a reboot (/var/run will be cleared). The root cause of the problem is a mismatch between client and server about where to connect, which is a configuration issue.