# How to enable regular linux users to access postgres database without sudo access?

Tags: postgresql, centos7, sudo

We have a postgres database server(10.3) installed on Centos7, and created a database with the name of "db_name". We have database access. The setting in pg_hba.conf is as the following:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

When I have sudo access, I can access the database "db_name".

```
[root@localhost bin]# sudo -s       
[root@localhost bin]# psql -U db_name db_user
psql (10.3)
Type "help" for help.

db_name=>
```

When I tried to access database as a regular linux user, I got the following error:

```
[linuxuser@localhost bin]# psql -U db_name db_user
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The reason we want to limit some users sudo access is that our report specialists need an access to the database "db_name", but we don't want them to have the sudo privilege to do something else.

What kind of settings shall I do in order to make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: Try a TCP connection: `psql -h -U username dbname`. Additionally: you did not mention you created a user, only a database. When you create a database, Postgres does not automatically create a user for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. 
The cause of the problem is that there is no /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 file existed.
By default, unix_socket_directories is '/tmp' which is set in postgresql.conf.

For some reason, the regular linux user is not looking at /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432, but instead looking at /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 file.

So the fix is as the following:

```
cd /var/run
mkdir postgresql 
cd postgresql/ 
ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 .s.PGSQL.5432
```

The following command works as well.

```
psql -h /tmp -U db_user db_name
```

Comment: You saved my day

Comment: Short version : 
`sudo mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you should create a role to access the DB.

For that you will have to do this:

1. Change to postgres account (Created during installation of postgresql)

   ```
   $ sudo -i -u postgres
   ```
2. Create a new role

   ```
   postgres@server createuser --interactive

   Output
   Enter name of role to add: DB_Name
   Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
   ```
3. Create Database

   ```
   postgres@server createdb DB_Name
   ```
4. Create user, change to user and access to database

   ```
   $ sudo adduser DB_Name
   $ sudo -i -u DB_Name
   $ psql
   DB_Name=# \conninfo
   ```

References:

[How To Install and Use PostgreSQL on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-7#connect-to-postgres-with-the-new-user)